# Jest mocks bleeding between tests, reset isn't fixing it

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

Testing two modules, `helper` which makes use of `render`. It's possible for `render` to throw, so I handle that in `helper`, and I want tests to ensure that's working as expected.

When I originally wrote the tests, I wrote what was needed for that test in the test itself, including mocks, using `jest.doMock`. Once all the tests pass I wanted to refactor to share mocks where possible.

So this code works great:

```js
test('throws', async () => {
    jest.doMock('./render', () => jest.fn(async () => { throw new Error('mock error'); }));

    const helper = require('./helper');

    expect(async () => { helper(); }).rejects.toThrow('mock error');
    expect(log_bug).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test('succeeds', async () => {
    jest.doMock('./render', () => jest.fn(async () => 'rendered result'));

    const helper = require('./helper');

    expect(await helper()).toEqual(true); //helper uses rendered result but doesn't return it
    expect(log_bug).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

HOWEVER, these are not the only two tests and by far most of the other tests that mock render want it to return its success state. I tried to refactor that success use-case out to a file in `__mocks__/render.js` like so:

```js
// __mocks__/render.js
module.exports = jest.fn(async () => 'rendered result');
```

And then refactor my tests to this, to be more DRY:

```js
//intention: shared reusable "success" mock for render module
jest.mock('./render');

beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
});

test('throws', async () => {
    //intention: overwrite the "good" render mock with one that throws
    jest.doMock('./render', () => jest.fn(async () => { throw new Error('mock error'); }));

    const helper = require('./helper');

    expect(async () => { await helper(); }).rejects.toThrow('mock error');
    expect(log_bug).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

test('succeeds', async () => {
    //intention: go back to using the "good" render mock
    const helper = require('./helper');
    expect(await helper()).toEqual(true); //helper uses rendered result but doesn't return it
    expect(log_bug).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

With this updated test code, the error-logging test still works as expected -- the mock is overwritten to cause it to throw -- but then for the next test, the error is thrown again.

If I reverse the order of these tests so that the mock overwriting is last, then the failure doesn't happen, but that is clearly not the correct answer.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get my mock to properly reset after overriding it with `doMock`? The [doMock docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) do kind of illustrate what I'm trying to do, but they don't show mixing it with normal manual mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! I kept digging around and found [this somewhat similar Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50656680/751), which led me to try this approach instead of using `jest.doMock` to override inside of a test:

```js
//for this one test, overwrite the default mock to throw instead of succeed
const render = require('./render');
render.mockImplementation(async () => {
    throw new Error('mock error');
});
```

And with this, the tests pass no matter what order they run!